# Precision issue when using numpy.sin

Tags: numpy, precision, trigonometry

I am trying to generate a square wave starting from a sine wave using numpy.
I ran into a problem where:

- using the `numpy.pi` constant gives inaccurate results
- using the `3.14` constant gives me the correct result

To create the square wave the sign of the sine wave is taken and then the -1s are transformed into 0s using the maximum function.

```py
N = 15
x = np.arange(1, N)
s = np.maximum(np.sign(np.sin(3.14 * (x - 1))), np.zeros_like(x))
print(s)

>> [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
```

While using the constant for pi in numpy gives:

```py
N = 15
x = np.arange(1, N)
s = np.maximum(np.sign(np.sin(np.pi * (x - 1))), np.zeros_like(x))
print(s)

>> [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
```

where the sequence is not alternating 1s and 0s. With more elements you can observe patches of more than two 0s next to each other.

```
[0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

I am mostly trying to understand how using more precise values can lead to imprecise results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is **numerically unstable**. Using a higher precision will not solve the problem but just hide it a little bit more. The main issue is that `sin(PI * x)` should be theoretically always 0, but no *floating-point* function is perfect, so there is an error (typically 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)). This error change the sign of the result. This is what you observe. This problem is independent of the precision. Here is a geometrical illustration of what you compute:

[image]

If you just want alternated 0-1 values, you can add a shift to the `sin` function (eg. `np.maximum(np.sign(np.sin(np.pi * (x - 1) + np.pi/2)), np.zeros_like(x))`). If the shift is `pi/2`, then you can use a `cos` function.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to find why something like that isn't working, then inspect the intermediate results, and the reason might then become obvious.

```
>>> np.sin(np.pi * (np.arange(5)))
array([ 0.0000000e+00,  1.2246468e-16, -2.4492936e-16,  3.6739404e-16, -4.8985872e-16])
```

So the sin of an integer times pi is zero, and the above shows jitter at the limit of the float's precision. It could be positive or negative at random.